# How do we know if a distant galaxy's light we see today was also reaching our location before approximately 4.5 billion years (Earth formation)?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, galaxies

This has actually to do with the estimation of of how distant an observed galaxy is?

How we can be sure if we do not know if we could see the light comming from the galaxy even before the Earth was created thus more than 4.5 billion years ago?

Comment: How does knowing that something was visible in the past tell you anything about its distance?

Comment: @AndersSandberg Because then light would have travelled in less time to your location and therefore the distance is less.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a supernova explodes 10 billion light-years away from our current position. Its light pulse expands away in all directions. One of those directions is coincident with where the solar system, and the earth, will be at the present time.

The supernova light pulse travels steadily out into space. Meanwhile, the solar system forms and the earth condenses out of the dust. The sun ignites, the earth warms up, comets strike it, oceans form, life begins to evolve. The supernova pulse continues spreading.

Humans evolve, eventually scientists are born, telescopes are invented, and at some point the pulse enters one of those telescopes which happens to be pointed in the right direction.

Note that the emission of the light pulse is *causally disconnected* from its subsequent detection by that telescope, billions of years later. And since the light pulse *did not exist* before the supernova blew up, having a telescope pointed in the right direction one week, one year, ten years, or a million years sooner would not make any difference.

Comment: Imagine an estimated 10 Blyrs far away galaxy we see as today was also seen from our home location  (first light that reached the location) 4.5 Billion years before, What is the absolute distance to this galaxy 10 Blyrs or 5.5? Do you mean that the date that historically the light of this galaxy first reached our home location is not taken into account for calculating the current distance considering also in the meantime the expansion of the universe? Or for calculating its absolute age?